# Xamarin Studio 4.0.10 Android Project build fails with "Error initializing task PropertyGroup"

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

Using Xamarin Studio 4.0.10 on Mac OS/X 10.8.4 with latest updates from stable channel I am now getting the following error when trying to build a simple out of the box Android application project:

Error: Error initializing task PropertyGroup: Not registered task PropertyGroup. (BindableMap.Droid)

Anyone else getting this and if so were you able to solve it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I did have a similar issue with a target, but installing the latest Android build tools fixed that, now I'm left with this one, and I haven't found where this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Mono 3.2 (or later) since Xamarin.Android 4.8 uses a different compiler than the previous versions which requires Mono 3.2.

Comment: I just want to add that if you have Mono 3.2 installed and it still doesn't work, you probably haven't enabled Mono 3.2 as the active runtime in Xamarin Studio. To do so simply go to the top menu:

`Project-> Active Runtime-> Mono 3.2 (or something higher)`